# bootpag js pagination with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble getting bootpag (or any pagination, including easyPaginate, simplePagination, and pagerJS) to correctly work with my json list that creates divs for me. I've read some other topics that say you have to tell it to hide your divs and call an update then generate the list, but I am stuck.

I am new to js, and I have tried so many things but none work. Any ideas? My code is below.

```js
var data = [
  { title:'title1', alias:'coll1', description:'description1', },
  { title:'title2', alias:'coll2', description:'description2', },
  { title:'title3', alias:'coll3', description:'description3', },
  { title:'title4', alias:'coll4', description:'description4', },

]

data.sort(function(a, b){
var titleA=a.title.toLowerCase(), titleB=b.title.toLowerCase();
if (titleA < titleB) //sort string ascending
return -1;
if (titleA > titleB)
return 1;
return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
});

var collectionData= '';

for ( var key in data ) {
collectionData += '<div class="hvrbox">';
collectionData += '<div class="hvrbox-title"><h5>' + data[key].title + '</h5></div>';
collectionData += '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">';
collectionData += '<div class="hvrbox-layer_top hvrbox-layer_slideup"><div class="hvrbox-text"><a href="#">';
collectionData += data[key].description + '</div><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>';
collectionData += '</a>';
collectionData += '</div></div>';
}


$('#collectionWrapper').append(collectionData);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pagination').bootpag({
            total: 4,
            page: 1,
            maxVisible:1,
        }).on('page', function(event, num){
             $('#collectionWrapper').html("Page" + num); // some ajax content loading...

        });
});
```

```css
/*container for collections list*/
#collectionWrapper {
  grid-area: collectionWrapper;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hvrbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.hvrbox-title {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 12%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.hvrbox i {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:2%;
  right:3%;
  font-size: 3em;
  color:#E6AA3C;
}

.hvrbox img {
  width: 100%;
}

.hvrbox-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
  display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
  /* for old browsers */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: none;
}

.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
  display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideup,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="collectionWrapper">
</div>
<div id="pagination"></div>
```